# how to count key number start from 1 php

Tags: php, arrays, count

```
while(list($key,$val) = each($con_next)) {
    echo " $key $con_next[$key]\n";
}
```

result is

```
0 list item 1
1 list item 2
2 list item 3
3 list item 4
```

but i want result

```
1 list item 1
2 list item 2
3 list item 3
4 list item 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array are default starts from `0` so you have to add `1` to it

```
echo ($key +1). " $con_next[$key]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that your arrays start counting from 0. An easy solution is to increase your counters. Instead of allowing $key to start count from 1, add +1 to it and it counts 0 + 1, 1 + 1,.... That way you get what you want.

while(list($key,$val) = each($con_next)) {

echo ($key + 1) . "$con_next[$key]\n";

}